# Typescript TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extract words from a string using the following:

```
export class AddContactCtrl implements IAddContactCtrl {

    middleNamesString: string;

    saveContact() {
        var middleNames : string[] = this.middleNamesString.split(" ");
    }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null
>   reference

Why is this the case? `this.middleNamesString` is of type `string`, which should have the `split()` method, yet it returns null/undefined? I suspect it has something to do with the way I'm using `this`, but I'm not sure why.

I've tried removing the `middleNames` string array type, to no effect. It does work if I change it to a local variable like so:

```
var randomString = "Random Name";
var middleNames : string[] = randomString.split(" ");
```

But why?

Comment: You did not assign middleNamesString. Use a debugger and you should see. Your code excerpt above does not show where you would assign it.

Comment: Tip : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvocUcbCupA

Comment: @basarat I actually watched your video before posting. From what you explain in the video my usage of `this` is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the emitted JS?  There's two possibilities.

The first is you're never assigning a value to `middleNamesString`.  With the JS emitted from TypeScript classes, members don't exist until they get initialized with a value (or a placeholder like `undefined` or `null`).  If you haven't assigned a value to `middleNamesString`, then it is `undefined`, and you can't call `.split()` on `undefined`.

The other possibility is that with the way you're calling the method, `this` is pointing to the global scope (such as the `window` object if your code is running in the browser.)  In this case, you want to use an arrow function which will rewrite calls to `this` to point to the current class instance in TypeScript (and ES6).

```
saveContact = () => {
    var middleNames : string[] = this.middleNamesString.split(" ");
}
```

This still assumes that `middleNamesString` has been assigned a value before saveContact is called.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't initialized middNamesString. In this case my usage of `this` was correct.